# Laravel migrate doesnt work properly on Plesk server

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, plesk, laravel-passport

I have a laravel app with api. I use Passport to authenticate and manage tokens. On my mac everything work, but when i deploy it and run `php artisan migrate` it only migrate files that in **project/database/migrations**. There is another migrations files in **project/vendor/laravel/passport/database/migrations** there are dont migrate on server, but migrate on my local machine.

Comment: Try this " php artisan migrate --path =vendor/laravel/passport/database/migrations "

Comment: This command work, but it should migrate after **php artisan migrate** command. php artisan migrate --path =vendor/laravel/passport/database/migrations after this my api doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are some permission problems. You could check that with `ls -l` on the `project/vendor/` directory.

Another way is to publish the migrations
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations`

Comment: How can i check permissions? Is there some file?

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations doesnt help